# Link to image in popup (R leaflet)

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I used the code mentioned in other topics here:

```
link <- c("https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/4okYLMcxk2ZjRqWwSwU8WkEcRQA4NRYxYrlZjieGCace9oNl2DYC78-ZsfIUxu2GKh2_SoPOWluXll2Sl5P0uJxCDPFW_uzQqsW_oHOQ9ept44Ex87I0yw_5EhD6nR1aIRiM")

addCircleMarkers(lng = ~ X, lat = ~ Y, radius = 3, fillColor = ~ species_5,
               stroke = F, fillOpacity = 0.5,
               popup = paste0("<img src='", link, "' />")
```

But image doesn't appear in the popup window. Since this image is uploaded from KML file, the link doesnt have ".jpg" part. You can check link. How to refer to that with aim to show image in the popup?
Thanks

Comment: Remove the single quotes. `paste0("<img src = ", link, " />")`

Comment: Phil, it doesnt help. Link doesnt have ".jpg" or ".png" or any else part like an image. I am searching for other way showing image using such links...

Comment: (1) Your code is missing an ) at the end. (2) that may be a png file rather than jpg

Comment: Henry, thanks but with that it also doesnt work. I suggest there is some trouble in my RStudip Viewer. Since answer below should work.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a reproducible example would make it easier to solve your issue. Here's one that works for me:

```
library(leaflet)
data(quakes)

link <- "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/4okYLMcxk2ZjRqWwSwU8WkEcRQA4NRYxYrlZjieGCace9oNl2DYC78-ZsfIUxu2GKh2_SoPOWluXll2Sl5P0uJxCDPFW_uzQqsW_oHOQ9ept44Ex87I0yw_5EhD6nR1aIRiM"

leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, label = ~as.character(mag), popup = paste0("<img src = ", link, " />"))
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to be good, and I reproduced this code. Actually, it is the same to my code. And now I realized that it is just something in my R Viewer or something else since it is not shown again :(